# Incrementing the list title name with numbers in Python

Tags: python, list

I am unable to increment the number in my list name as i need a list name going from 0 to 24, i've tried to use the concatenation but it didn't work.

Folllowing is my example code:

```
d.last0 = [0,0]
d.last1 = [0,0]
d.last2 = [0,0]
d.last3 = [0,0]
d.last4 = [0,0]
.
.
d.last24 = [0,0]
```

As you see, this intialization goes till 24, what i want to do to bring this under loop so i can make the code more faster and efficient, but when i call this as

> d["last_{i}"]

it didn't return any data, also tried with this:

> d["last{i]".GetValue]

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary of lists?

Comment: I'm new to python, any example to use dictionary in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below dictionary code to meet your requirement,

```
d={}     # declare the dictionary
d['last0'] = [0,0]  #assigning the values to dictionary
print(d)  # verify for the values

# to meet your requirement to have 24 values increment, loop and update the dict
dic={}
for i in range(25):
    dic.update({'last'+str(i):[0,0]})

print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by using hash tables (dictionaries). These allow you to use a key and associate data with that key. Here is your problem solved with a dictionary in python:

```
d = {}
for i in range(25):
    d['last' + str(i)] = [0,0]

print(d['last24']) # prints [0,0]
```

If you insist on having 25 different variables, you can use the globals() keyword in python, which you can edit like this:

```
for i in range(25):
   globals()['last' + str(i)] = [0,0]

print(last24) # prints [0,0]
```